# Stripe SDK with Woocommerce

Tags: ios, sdk, stripe-payments

I am trying to setup stripe iOS SDK in my app to integrate with my woocommerce site which has been configured with stripe as a payment method

I am confused as the sdk requires a baseurl which seems integrate with a separate host service.

SO if integrating with a woocommerce enabled site.  do I need a separate baseurl service ? or should I be setting some other configuration options.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need a fully separate service (outside of a WooCommerce hosted site) that can accept certain request arguments.  You need to have something that can build ephemeral keys for you.  As far as I know, WooCommerce sites don't support this feature out of the box.